# How to set property in a test step property file of soapui through command line

Tags: batch-file, groovy, soapui

My requirement is to set a property in a Test step property file of soapui through command line.

There is a option that we can set project property through command line by using

-P  Sets or overrides project property with name=value but here i want to set a property in a test step property file .

for that I didn't get any option can anyone please help me on this .

Thanks

Comment: May be you want to add the use case ? Probably not using in right manner. Yes, there is no command line option for the same. Can you not use the project property?

Comment: No actually I need to set it in Test Step property file only .

Comment: You already have answer to that, I believe. And if you can explain the use case, it would be better to achieve the same in alternative ways.

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/working-with-properties.html#2-Setting-properties-from-the-command-line

Comment: Apologies, I take that  back. Thank you @SiKing for rightly pointing the documentation.